# Подключение статических ресурсов во vue js

Tags: vue.js

Работаю во vue. И возникла проблема с подключением скриптов к проекту. Скрипты содержат в себе плагины и в одном скрипте эти плагины непосредственно используются, взаимодействуя с элементами страницы.
Вопрос такой: как правильно подключать скрипты? Я перепробовал множество способов, а именно через тег скрипт в index.html/через require в main.js/ и все это или не работает вообще, или же работает некорректно. Подскажите, куда класть скрипты и как указывать к ним путь?

Answer (score 0):

Если подключаете в конкретном компоненте, то можете сделать это следующим образом:

```
<script>
export default {
  import * as myFile from '../assets/js/myFile.js'
}
</script>
```

Можете то же самое использовать и глобально для всех компонентов, если добавите эту строку в `App.vue`

Или можете в `index.html` стандартно подключать, например из папки `static`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My site</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/static/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="/static/my-script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ. Из папки static подключение работает. Но только при перезагрузке страницы. При смене компонента скрипты не работают, пока не перезагрузишь страницу.